# python log level not setting

Tags: python, logging

In file 1:

```
def get_logger():
    return logging.getLogger(_LOGGER_NAME)


def init_logger():
    message_format = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s %(name)s >>> %(message)s',
                                       datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')

    console_info_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    console_info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    console_info_handler.setFormatter(fmt=message_format)

    logger = logging.getLogger(_LOGGER_NAME)
    logger.addHandler(console_info_handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    return logger
```

In file 2:

```
if name == '__main__':
    logger = get_logger()
    logger.info(logger.level)
```

Does not print anything (imports are in place of course). And if I go:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = get_logger()
    logger.critical(logger.level)
```

The output is 0, instead of the expected 20. So it looks like the logger level isn't set at the level that I thought it was. Moreover, the level is lower than I thought it was, yet it still doesn't log on logger.info. What am I doing wrong here? Oh and bonus question (since I stole the above code and don't know any of python's logging intricacies), how does resolution of a log message happen if the logger's level and the handler's level clash?

Comment: What is `_LOGGER_NAME`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File 2 only calls `get_logger()` and not `init_logger()`. Thus, setLevel is never called on the logger, so its given the default value of `NOTSET`.

Take a look at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel

By default, the root logger is created with level `WARNING`. This is why `logger.info(logger.level)` does nothing as `INFO` is below `WARNING`. `logger.critical(logger.level)`, on the other hand, outputs 0 as this is the numeric value of `NOTSET`.

To have it do what you want, just call `init_logger()` in your second file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = init_logger()
    logger.info(logger.level)
```

To answer your bonus question: the handler gets whatever messages get through the logger.

If the level of the logger is `DEBUG`, and the level of the handler is `INFO`, the handler will receive all messages from the `DEBUG` Level and up, but will only output messages on the `INFO` level and up.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `init_logger()` (before calling `logger.info()`) so the level of your non-default `_LOGGER_NAME` was not set.

Also note the typo: `if name == '__main__':` -> `if __name__ == '__main__':`